# help for sentence analysis

Tags: grammar, american-english

> the conveying to an employee of unconditional entitlement to a share in a pension fund

([Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=vesting%20definition&rlz=1CAVNXA_enUS854&oq=vesting&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.1201j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

To me the sentence are just different confusing components: `the conveying`; `to an employee`; `of unconditional entitlement`; 
`to a share`; `in a pension fund`.

For example, `in a pension fund` which subject it describes? `a share`, `entitlement` or employee``` ?

The same question for `to a share` :  what to a share? Does it describe the conveying to a share or the employee to a share?

I can understand easy-structured sentence but this one has so many parallel combinations of prep. and noun.

Edit:
After reading it repeatedly, I think a better grouping would be like this:
  `the conveying to an employee` and
  `unconditional entitlement to a share in a pension fund` 
Hope my question makes sense y'all. ..
Thank you for helping out.

Comment: That's only a sentence fragment—or a noun phrase. Although more complex and involving more components, it's effectively no different than simply writing *the ball that rolled*. What about it? There is a verb, but it's not the main verb of the sentence (which is missing). Instead, it's just part of the noun phrase. As in ***[the boy who ran away from home]*** *was found safe and sound.* The phrase in the question is ***[the conveying to an employee of unconditional entitle to a share in a pension fund***]. What about it? How does the sentence end? *⋯ was unwise*? *⋯ was a good idea*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conveying of something to an employee. That something is "entitlement to a share in a fund" (having the rights for a share in a fund). After adding adjectives that something becomes "unconditional entitlement to a share in a pension fund". Where unconditional means that it can't be denied or taken back.

The constructions are: "entitlement to (sth)", "conveying of (sth)", "conveying to (someone)", share in (something)".

That's how i get it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you.  Your post is really clear. One more question here. For example "entitlement to (sth)" , I have problem in finding where "sth" is. How you figure out what "sth" is?  Is it always the element closest to entitlement?